# "Omni-relevant" alternative?

Tags: synonyms

I'm coding a database, and in that database I have a set of players. Players have attributes, but only some of these attributes are relevant for all sports.

Is there a nice, shorter term for "relevant for all sports"? I know it's a bit of a stretch, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I don't think there is a word thet means 'relevant for all sports'..are you looking for a word to replace relevant?

Comment: @Josh61 - You're right. One word might be tricky. Two words would do fine, but the Mess Detector thinks three is too much for a column name.

Comment: +1 for the way you've phrased your request, making no unwarranted assumptions.

Comment: *General* or *generic*?

Comment: Why not try thinking about that in English, and looking for an answer in English and then if you really have to, translating that answer into whatever language you want to use?

Answer (score 2):

**sport-agnostic** might do, just as we have a **language-agnostic** tag in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The term ***universally relevant*** could work, if the way it should be interpreted is obvious from the context.

Answer (score 0):

you could try **Global**, like a global variable in programming.